# Can we write a google doc form in Qt?

Tags: qt, google-docs-api

I am developing an app in Qt and want to write into a Google Doc form automatically as the result. Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the Google Docs API, not qt. Guessing from [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#what_can_this_api_do), it seems to be possible:

> The Google Documents List API allows developers to create, retrieve, update, and delete Google Docs (including but not limited to text documents, spreadsheets, presentations, and drawings), files, and collections.

Comment: You basicly issue HTTP requests according to the API, qt provides the handy `QHttp` class. On how to structure these requests, take a look at eg: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#uploading_a_new_document_or_file_with_both_metadata_and_content

Comment: Anybody can please provide me the code, as I am a newbie to html. Thanks

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with HTML. And without knowing what you are trying to do, there is no chance we can help you. You might want to close this question as answered and ask a new question involving your C++ structures you need to "push" to Google Docs.